# Get full stack trace message of Axis2

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis

I am writing a Java EE web application using Tomcat and Axis2 on `Eclipse EE`.
There is an error in the code, and I can't get the full stack trace to debug it.
I am doing a JDBC connection, and something fails. When I do this using a normal main function it works, but through the Tomcat/Axis2 it does not work.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at merge.Test.testQuery(Test.java:36)
    ... 35 more
```

How can I expand these 35 lines?

I have set to true the following options in `axis2.xml`:
true
true

Also I enabled the following option in `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE
```

but I haven't found any log files in the apache directory, or in the axis2 directory, or in the projects directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see the log on the standard output as well.

On Eclipse, just click the following button:

[image]

It will switch to the `Tomcat`'s output.